# android - threads - create buttons in Thread

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I need to add a button to my activity.

The problem is that the function to do that is in thread , so when i use "this" keyword to add button to the activity , the app crashes.

Call thread code :

```
public void Favourites_Tab_Click(Menu menu , View view)
 {
  setContentView(R.layout.default_layout_tab);
  new Thread(new Create_Button_On_Favourite_Activity()).start();
 }
```

- The Favourites_Tab_Click method called when itam clicked

Thread Code :

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void Create_New_Contact_Buttons(final String Text_View_Object , String Text_View_Subject , int Text_Font_Size , int Text_Color  , int Back_Ground_Color , int Contact_ID)
 {
  final TextView Text_View_Display=new Button(getApplicationContext());

  Text_View_Display.setText(Text_View_Object+"/"+Text_View_Subject);
  Text_View_Display.setTextColor(Text_Color);

  Text_View_Display.setTextSize(Text_Font_Size);

  if(Contact_ID != 0)
   {
    Text_View_Display.setId(Contact_ID);

    Text_View_Display.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
     {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v)
       {
        String text = Text_View_Object.toString();//Text_View_Display_ID.getText().toString()
        if(text != "")
         {
          Messages_Tab_Click(null, v);
          Intent Sessions_Activity = new Intent(Text_View_Display.getContext(), Sessions_Activity.class);
          startActivity(Sessions_Activity);
         }
       }
     });
   }
  this.addContentView(Text_View_Display, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(768, 50));
 }
```

So how i can resolve that ?

Comment: Can you post more code? How do you define and run your thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are in an instance of `Thread` `this` will refer to that instance. You need the instance of your `Activity`.

Use the following to access the instance of your activity:

`YourActivityName.this.addContentView(Text_View_Display, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(768, 50));`

Note that it is in general not good practice to add buttons from the non-UI thread (it is even hard to do so). Take a look at the `AsyncTask` class. In the `onPostExecute()` method you can create and place the button.

Comment: the code doesnt work to me . i wrote my activity  name before "this" and Eclipse says that my activity "default_layout_tab" need to defined .

Comment: 1) threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception
2)android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: That is why I placed my note about buttons from the non-UI thread. Take a look at it.